# Node.js synchronously with mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, synchronous

I am trying to implement a synchronous query in mysql with node.js, I tried several ways and did not succeed

I am new to node.js

I use express.js

**connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connMySql = function() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
            host : 'localhost',
            user : 'root',
            password : '******', 
            database : 'ress'
        });

}

module.exports = function() {
    return connMySql;

}
```

**DAO.js**

```
function UserDAO(connection){

    this._connection = connection(); 
}


UserDAO.prototype.createUser = function (user, callback){

    var sql = "insert into... ";

    this._connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
        //console.log(result)
        //console.log()
        if (err){
            callback(err,false )

        }
        if (result){

            var newI = result.insertId

            var sqlOther = "insert into ..... ";

            this._connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
                if (err){
                    callback(err,false )
                }else if (result.length > 0){


                    callback(false, result.insertId)
                }
            }); 


        }
    }); 
}
```

I try implements await, async and Promisse(.then) but no success.

What I need to make calls synchronously and return insert id?

thanks

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal No error, but my insert had 15 querys and I need insert id for others querys

Comment: Promisify the library, then use async/await

Answer (score 0):

From mysql repo I see that you're missing connection.connect()

Answer (score 0):

**connection.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '******', 
    database : 'ress'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

**DAO** *_connection must be closed when it's done with it's job*

```
UserDAO.prototype.createUser = function (user, callback){
    var sql = "insert into... ";
    this._connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
        //console.log(result)
        //console.log()
        if (err){
            callback(err,false )
            this._connection.end();
        }
        if (result){
            var newI = result.insertId
            var sqlOther = "insert into ..... ";
            this._connection.query(sql, function(err, result){
                if (err){
                    callback(err,false )
                } else if (result.length > 0){
                    callback(false, result.insertId)
                }
                this._connection.end();
            }); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: @MarcusMenezes are you able to see the records in first & second tables?

Comment: yes my code works, what I need is change my code to synchronous call.

Comment: why? are you not getting inserted id in `callback`?

Comment: yes, but i need call others querys inside the closures, I have 15 inserts to do and inside the clousers I can not reference a Insert ID from a previous insert

Comment: TBH you can't make it synchronous, if you want to optimize your code you can use promise in order to overcome from `callback hell`.